# React Router does not display any of my configured routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I am trying to set up a simple app using react-router, but no matter what I type in the URL, nothing is displayed where the BrowserRouter is set up.

Here is my code:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

import {BrowserRouter,Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom';

import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import MyApp from './MyApp';
import Deducciones from './Deducciones';
import MainMenu from './MainMenu';

class App extends Component {
render() {
return (
  <div className="App">
  <BrowserRouter>
      <div>
          <header className="App-header">
            <img src={logo} className="App-logo" alt="logo" />
            <h1 className="App-title">Welcome to My App</h1>
          </header>
          <Route exact path="/" Component={MainMenu} />
          <Route exact path="/myapp" Component={MyApp} />
          <Route exact path="/deduc" Component={Deducciones} />
      </div>
   </BrowserRouter>

  </div>
);
}
}

export default App;
```

I tried typing http://localhost:3000/, http://localhost:3000/myapp, and http://localhost:3000/deduc into the url, but nothing is ever displayed except for the logo.

I also trying using a   to enclose my routes but it was the same result. Can someone tell me what I am missing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be `component` lowercase not `Component` upper case that why your router is probably not working

```
  <Route exact path="/" component={MainMenu} />
  <Route exact path="/myapp" component={MyApp} />
  <Route exact path="/deduc" component={Deducciones} />
```

Comment: Thanks. I guess my code-completion must be acting weird.

Comment: You saved my day !